# Why does a particular value in a view show differently than the value in the corresponding table?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a view in oracle that I have created by joining two tables, product and product_details. There is a column named harmonizedcode in the view that takes the values from the harmonized code from the product_details. But there are some values of harmonized code in the view that does not match the harmonized code corresponding to the table product_details. What could cause this error, and how to fix this error?

Comment: you should show atleast view script and both table datatype.also what error is being thrown .My first doubts is datatype.

Comment: @KumarHarsh the atatype of Harmonization code in tha table productDetails is of varchar, from this table i have created a view that takes the value of the harmonization code. The join is made by joining table productDetails with table product through the product_id field. It is just that when I checked the view , some values taken as harmonization code do not match the values in productDetails. I want to know what is causing this. I tried recompiling my view but it is still not fixed.